Duplicate items returned in PG_Featureserv query with OWSLib
I've got a postgis DB with Pg_Featureserv running as the OGC API for querying a collection of data. I'm querying the data using python and OWSLib.
The data itself is some raster and GPS records aggregated over a grid. So I should be getting one grid cell with a couple data field. No duplicate or missing grid cells are expected.
I have to handle pagination from PG_featserv and I do this with a loop that exits when fewer rows than the limit are returned:
def get_all_features(feature_collection, collection_name, limit = 10000): 
    '''
    This seems to fetch duplicates... This might be due to the DB not sorting the output? sortby=PROP
    '''
    offset = 0
    not_fetched_all = True
    appended_data = []
    while not_fetched_all:
        # print(offset)
        rows = feature_collection.collection_items(collection_name, limit=limit, offset=offset)
        rows_fetched = rows['numberReturned']  
        gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(rows['features'])
        appended_data.append(gdf)
        gdf = None
        offset = offset + rows_fetched
        not_fetched_all = rows_fetched == limit
    all_gdf = pd.concat(appended_data).reset_index()
    return all_gdf

The problem is that I'm getting duplicate rows:
    index   geometry    asphalt_length  built_area  canopy_max  canopy_mean canopy_min  canopy_stddev   gid highway_length  id  pop_total   surface_max surface_mean    surface_min surface_stddev
99980   9980    POLYGON ((-77.11487 39.15644, -77.11469 39.156...   NaN NaN 0   0.000000    0   0.000000    100264  NaN 100264  5.136608    14  2.777778    0   5.244633
99981   9981    POLYGON ((-77.11488 39.15691, -77.1147 39.1566...   NaN NaN 29  5.222222    0   10.108058   100265  NaN 100265  3.556930    18  3.000000    0   6.000000
99982   9982    POLYGON ((-77.1149 39.15738, -77.11472 39.1571...   NaN NaN 27  5.222222    0   9.908221    100266  NaN 100266  3.556930    13  2.000000    0   4.189935
99983   9983    POLYGON ((-77.11491 39.15784, -77.11473 39.157...   NaN NaN 46  7.666667    0   15.333333   100267  NaN 100267  1.778465    12  2.000000    0   3.771236

and
index   geometry    asphalt_length  built_area  canopy_max  canopy_mean canopy_min  canopy_stddev   gid highway_length  id  pop_total   surface_max surface_mean    surface_min surface_stddev
100348  348 POLYGON ((-77.11291 39.10849, -77.11273 39.108...   NaN NaN 0   0.000000    0   0.000000    100758  NaN 100758  NaN 0   0.0 0   0.000000
100349  349 POLYGON ((-77.11488 39.15691, -77.1147 39.1566...   NaN NaN 29  5.222222    0   10.108058   100265  NaN 100265  3.556930    18  3.0 0   6.000000
100350  350 POLYGON ((-77.1149 39.15738, -77.11472 39.1571...   NaN NaN 27  5.222222    0   9.908221    100266  NaN 100266  3.556930    13  2.0 0   4.189935
100351  351 POLYGON ((-77.11491 39.15784, -77.11473 39.157...   NaN NaN 46  7.666667    0   15.333333   100267  NaN 100267  1.778465    12  2.0 0   3.771236

My thinking is that this could be due to the DB returning the items out of order (in which case I should add a "order by gid" into the SQL query), or that the way PG-Featureserv and/or OWSLib handles offsets isn't ideal.
Does anyone have any idea of how I "should" handle this? I see nothing in the PG_Featserv docs about explicitly sorting the results, and also nothing in OWSLib about requesting the results be sorted in CQL or what not.
EDIT:  I've narrowed it down to a potential bug with PG_featureserv where the rows returned from the query are not the same even though the view is materialized and an "order by GID" implemented in the SQL definition. Might need to build an index? Problem was not having a "sort by=GID" in the query parameter. So now the problem has shifted to:
How do I get CQL working in OWSLib so that the generated URL contains a sortby field. It seems like it should work but not even the examples of CQL usage in OWSLib are working in my setup

Have you tried the sortby option listed in the doc?

PS: and while at it, it would be more efficient to add a where clause similar to gid > last_found_gid and to ditch the offset.

Those are some good suggestions. I'll implement them, I'm not too sure how CQL works with OWSLib and WFS but I'll try figure it out

The problem was that there was no "orderby=gid" being passed to the SQL query being generated by OWSLib. Without ordering the database would spit out a semi random row.
To get ordering working (and therefore to get a complete/non duplicate dataset from multiple queries) the following code works:
from owslib.ogcapi.features import Features 
w = Features('http://localhost:9000')
w.collection_items(collection_id = 'my_feature_collection', limit=1, offset=15000, sortby='gid')

